# toggle ngClass in nested ngRepeat

Tags: angularjs

I have a nested ngRepeat and I have to apply some css class on each item in nested structure when I click on some div. This is what I have till now (simplified version of code) -

**View**

```
<div ng-repeat="item in vm.userItems">
    <div ng-repeat="child in item.children" ng-class="vm.childSelected($parent.$index,$index)" ng-click="vm.toggleChild($parent.$index,$index)">
        <div class="panel-body">
            {{:: child.name}}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
vm.isChildSelected = [];

vm.toggleChild = function (parentId, id) {

    vm.isChildSelected[parentId, id] = (vm.isChildSelected[parentId, id] == "" || vm.isChildSelected[parentId, id] == undefined) ? "goal-added" : "";

    //classes change for every nth element in each column - NOT WHAT I WANT
    console.info(vm.isChildSelected[0, 0] + "," + vm.isChildSelected[1, 0] + "," + vm.isChildSelected[2, 0] + "," + vm.isChildSelected[3, 0] + "," + vm.isChildSelected[4, 0]);   

    //Setting of class/passing argument is just fine 
    console.info(parentId + "," + id + ":" + vm.isChildSelected[parentId, id]);    //works just fine
};

vm.childSelected = function (parentId, id) {
    return vm.isChildSelected[parentId, id];
};
```

The problem I have is that on console, I see everything logged correctly when I set the class on a div on clicking, but when ng-class expression is evaluated, classes change for every nth element in each column.

I think the problem lies with how I have declared the array. Any pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about simple solution:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in vm.userItems">
    <div ng-repeat="child in item.children" ng-class="{'goal-added':flag}" ng-click="flag=!flag">
        <div class="panel-body">
            {{:: child.name}}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Works great. I over-complicated it :)